# getting error while parsing chat massage to another chat room

Tags: elixir, chat, phoenix-framework

I am getting error message while sending message to chat room

Room_channel.ex

```
 def join("room:" <> _user, _, socket) do
    send self(), :after_join
    {:ok, socket}
  end

  def handle_info(:after_join, socket) do
     {_, value} = Redix.command(:redix, ["GET", socket.assigns.user])
    Presence.track(socket, socket.assigns.user, %{
      online_at: :os.system_time(:millisecond),
      status: value
    })
    push socket, "presence_state", Presence.list(socket)
    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  def handle_in("message:new", message, socket) do

    broadcast! socket, "message:new", %{
      user: socket.assigns.user,
      body: message,
      timestamp: :os.system_time(:millisecond)
    }
    PhoenixChat.Endpoint.subscribe("room:" <> message["to"]) 
    PhoenixChat.Endpoint.broadcast!("room:" <> message["to"], "message:new",%{
        user: socket.assigns.user,
        body: message,
        timestamp: :os.system_time(:millisecond)
   })
    milisecondstime = :os.system_time(:millisecond)
    [room, user] = String.split(Map.get(socket, :topic), ":")
    data = Poison.encode!(%{"created_at" => :os.system_time(:millisecond), "updated_at" => :os.system_time(:millisecond), "uuid" => UUID.uuid1(), "date" => :os.system_time(:millisecond), "from" => user, "to" => message["to"], "message" => message["value"]})
    Redix.command(:redix, ["SET", UUID.uuid1(), data]) 
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

this is the console error message

```
[info] Replied room:Pamidu :ok
[error] GenServer #PID<0.464.0> terminating
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in PhoenixChat.RoomChannel.handle_info/2
    (phoenix_chat) web/channels/room_channel.ex:14: PhoenixChat.RoomChannel.handle_info(%Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast{event: "message:new", payload: %{body: %{"to" => "rusiru", "value" => "fuck you "}, timestamp: 1501499563929, user: "abc"}, topic: "room:rusiru"}, %Phoenix.Socket{assigns: %{user: "abc"}, channel: PhoenixChat.RoomChannel, channel_pid: #PID<0.464.0>, endpoint: PhoenixChat.Endpoint, handler: PhoenixChat.UserSocket, id: nil, joined: true, pubsub_server: PhoenixChat.PubSub, ref: nil, serializer: Phoenix.Transports.WebSocketSerializer, topic: "room:abc", transport: Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, transport_name: :websocket, transport_pid: #PID<0.421.0>})
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/channel/server.ex:239: Phoenix.Channel.Server.handle_info/2
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:601: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:667: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: %Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast{event: "message:new", payload: %{body: %{"to" => "rusiru", "value" => "fuck you "}, timestamp: 1501499563929, user: "abc"}, topic: "room:rusiru"}
State: %Phoenix.Socket{assigns: %{user: "abc"}, channel: PhoenixChat.RoomChannel, channel_pid: #PID<0.464.0>, endpoint: PhoenixChat.Endpoint, handler: PhoenixChat.UserSocket, id: nil, joined: true, pubsub_server: PhoenixChat.PubSub, ref: nil, serializer: Phoenix.Transports.WebSocketSerializer, topic: "room:abc", transport: Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, transport_name: :websocket, transport_pid: #PID<0.421.0>}
```

here I am creating user wise chat rooms and passing message and user name that message should be delivered to.
Messages are passing without issue but from the console, it shows this error. I have no idea about this and finding a way to fix this issue.
Is there any way to fix this error?

line 14 is this

```
def handle_info(:after_join, socket) do
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Phoenix.Channel](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#module-subscribing-to-external-topics) docs:

Note: the caller must be responsible for preventing duplicate subscriptions. After calling `subscribe/1` from your endpoint, the same flow applies to handling regular Elixir messages within your channel. Most often, you’ll simply relay the `%Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast{}` event and payload:

```
alias Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast
def handle_info(%Broadcast{topic: _, event: ev, payload: payload}, socket) do
  push socket, ev, payload
  {:noreply, socket}
end
```